# add & delete a new route in routing table using batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

Im using a work PC with 2 interface, mostly i add manual routes to my `10.0.0.0` network to access our internal network.

I got tired of doing this and wanted to create batch script file. but i have limited knowledge on it.

I just needed to delete and add route on the routing table of windows, as follows:

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 10.1.1.1
route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.1.1.1
echo 'complete'
```

Comment: And what happens when you do this? FYI:http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728112(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: open a notepad -> add the lines you have posted -> save the file as `routeadd.bat`. That's it.

Comment: @Rahul not sure what im doing wrong, but i did test that but it didn't worked.

Comment: `but it didn't worked` doesn't clarify much. Post the error message and exactly what have you tried.

Comment: i pasted this on a notepad. saved it as .bat, run the batch file as admin. (DOS pops a fraction of a sec. then closed). checked my `route print` but nothing has changed. No errors or anything appeared.

Comment: If you run those command separately, do they work fine?

Comment: ive tested by executing the `route delete 0.0.0.0 ..` command only. and nothing seems has change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure route `0.0.0.0` even exist. Try `route print` and see if they exist. Moreover, run those command as `admin`. Once you sure those route exist and those command works separately then just wrap them all in a bat file like

```
echo off
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 10.1.1.1
route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.1.1.1
echo on
echo 'complete'
```

Comment: im sure that the route exist, and i want to delete it. i have copy pasted the exact syntax you provided, run the batch as admin then check route print. the existing route didn't change/removed nor add a new route.

Comment: @bobbyjones, that can't be. try deleting a different existing route say `route delete 10.0.0.0` and similarly adding different route. Windows, does recreate the default `0.0.0.0` route.

Comment: hi Rahul, thanks for your help. i restarted my PC, and it now works fine. im really not sure why it didn't worked before the restart. there's something messing with my interface or route. didn't bother anymore to find the cause. its now working anyway. thanks.

Comment: @bobbyjones, those route values actually get stored in registry. may be something you have changed was not saved (just guessing). Anyways, glad that it works now.